# Age validation using the controller in C#

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I am using MVC4 to build up this project, and I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out how to take the pre-populated html

part that has a date of birth in it, and check it against the current days date to see if the person is above 18 or below 18. Depending on their age, i have a database that has a list of validation options for a drop down list that will display certain things depending on the age. If they are above 18, it will display 3 different results, if below 18, only 1 option will be available. I have tried a couple different ways, one of which worked fine by putting it in the View. But, I want to have this part running from the controller, I just want the logic separate from the ui. Here is the method that I'm working on for it, any help would be great! I've commented out an option or two that I've tried and hasn't worked.

```
public void SetupValidationList(DateTime? dateOfBirth = null)
    {
        var vtList = MetadataManager.GetValidationTypes().Where(x => x.DisplayInAdminTool).Select(x => x);

        // populate drop down for Validation Method/TypeID

        List<SelectListItem> items = vtList.Select(vtitem => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = vtitem.DisplayName,
            Value = vtitem.ID.ToString()
        }).ToList();
        items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = String.Empty, Value = String.Empty });

        // If minor then only validation option is face to face minor
        // If adult then remove face to face minor validation option
        if (dateOfBirth.HasValue)
        {
            //List<SelectListItem> validationList = new List<SelectListItem>();


            if (dateOfBirth >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18))
            {
                vtList(new SelectListItem { Text = "Patient Face to Face Minor" });
            }
            else
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Patient Face to Face" });
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Patient Phone" });
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Patient Notary" });
            }
            //if (Model.DateOfBirth >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18))
            //{
            //    validationList.Add(allValidationList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Text.Contains("Minor")));
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    validationList.AddRange(allValidationList.Where(s => !s.Text.Contains("Minor")));
            //}
        }

        ViewData["ValidationList"] = items;
    }
```

Comment: This is not Validation, it is business logic.

Comment: For context, we'd need to see what kind of (View)Model you are sending to the View.

Comment: Yes, and I would like the age checking part to be a part of the business logic.

Comment: [Display(Name = "Date of Birth:")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

This should work to my mind.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetSelectList(DateTime? dateOfBirth)
    {
   var vtList = MetadataManager.GetValidationTypes().Where(x => x.DisplayInAdminTool).Select(x => x);

        List<SelectListItem> myList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var items = (from n in vtList
                     select new SelectListItem
                     {
                       Text = vtitem.DisplayName,
                       Value = vtitem.ID.ToString()
                      }).ToList();

        foreach( var item in items)
          myList.Add(item);

          //I don't know, why you need this empty item:
         myList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = String.Empty, Value = String.Empty });

        if (dateOfBirth.HasValue)
        {
            if (dateOfBirth >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18))
            {
                 myList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Patient Face to Face Minor" });
            }
            else
            {
                 myList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Patient Face to Face" });
                 myList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Patient Phone" });
                 myList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Patient Notary" });
            }

        return myList; //or ViewBag.list = myList, if void()
    }
```

Comment: The empty item is the set default for when the page is loaded.